# How to set default for ng2-select

Tags: angular, ng2-bootstrap

> data(?Array) - Initial selection data to set. This should be an object with id and text properties in the case of input type 'Single', or an array of such objects otherwise. This option is mutually exclusive with value.

This is from the website documentation. GitHub calls for initData which throws an error.

I am setting [data] with an array of valid options, but nothing is selected. Additionally, I am seeing this even fire every time the dropdown is opened.

This also does not work in single mode.

How can I pre-select 'options' for this control?

I am using this with RC.1. Other solutions on SO look like older versions of ng2.

Comment: Can you please add some code that demonstrates what you have tried and what didn't work. What `ng2-select` are you using?

Comment: Actually, the demo doesn't work for multi - select. My code looks a lot like that.

Comment: https://valor-software.com/ng2-select/ tab to multiple. The place holder says no city selected. The TS code shows Athens should be selected. Similar code does not work for single as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://valor-software.com/ng2-select/ under the multiple tab shows the use of a [data] element. This is incorrect as per the project readme.

Replace [data] with [initData] and prepopulation works if the data is properly formatted.

Comment: I tried it and its not working , it says TypeError: this.initData.map is not a function

Comment: An example: > [initData]="[{ id:'example',text:'example' }]"

Answer (score 1):

you should use

```
<ng-select [active]="[periods[0]]" [data]="periods"></ng-select>
```

[image]

Comment: how about selecting multiple values? I got stuck with it. :(

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
<ng-select #my-select [multiple]="true" [items]="dataList"></ng-select>
```

Import the following classes:

```
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { SelectComponent, SelectItem } from 'ng2-select';
```

In the component class, access the `my-select` component using the `@ViewChild` decorator:

```
@ViewChild('my-select') mySelectComponent: SelectComponent;
```

Diving into ng2-select source code hints that the `active` property on `SelectComponent` holds the selected values. Also, `active` is an array of `SelectItem` objects. Thus, creating `SelectItem` objects and pushing them into the `active` array should allow you to programatically add/remove selected items.

Coming to your question, lets set a couple of default values for `ng2-select` :

```
ngOnInit() {
    if(!this.mySelectComponent.active) {
        this.mySelectComponent.active = new Array<SelectItem>();
    }
    this.mySelectComponent.active.push(new SelectItem("Apple"));
    this.mySelectComponent.active.push(new SelectItem("Banana"));
}
```

You can also clear all the existing values:

```
reset() {
    if(this.mySelectComponent.active) {
        this.mySelectComponent.active.length = 0;
    }
}
```

Note: The `SelectItem` constructor takes either a string or an object as parameter. If you pass in a string, the `id` and `text` will be set to the string value. In case you want to pass in different values for `id` and `text`, you can do this:

```
this.mySelectComponent.active.push(new SelectItem({id:'apl', text:'Apple'}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Current version docs explained better:   [ng2-select / valor-software.com](https://valor-software.com/ng2-select/)

**View side (*category-edit.component.html*):**

```
<ng-select [multiple]="true" [items]="tags" [active]="active_tags"></ng-select>
```

No matter if there is one or more elements, always must contain Array format, *Ex.: [{id: 1, text: MyText}] or [{id: 1, text: MyText1}, {id: 2, text: MyText2}]*

**Component side (*category-edit.component.ts*):**

```
import {Component, OnInit, Injectable} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class MyService {

   getTagsByCategoryId(id: string): Observable<any> { /** callback */}
}

export interface SelectOption{
   id?: string;
   text?: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-category-edit',
  templateUrl: 'category-edit.component.html'     
});

export class CategoriesComponent extends OnInit{
   tags: SelectOption[]; /** Assumed you already loaded these */ 
   active_tags: SelectOption[];     

 constructor(private myService:MyService){
   super();
 }
 ngOnInit(){
   this.init();
 }

 init(){

   const id= "the_id"; /** Some valid id to query */
   /** Callback */
   this.myService
       .getTagsByCategoryId(id)(
          response=> {
            if(response.error){ console.error(response.error);}   
            }else{
               console.log(response.result;)
               this.active_tags= <SelectOption[]> response.result;
            }  
          },
          error => {console.error(error);}
     );
 }
```

}